# How to remove spacing between form fields while using Bootstrap Flask's render_form_row

Tags: flask, bootstrap-4, jinja2, bootstrap-flask

How can I use something like "no-gutters" while using this **render_form_row** *bootstrap-flask* function?

https://bootstrap-flask.readthedocs.io/en/stable/macros.html#id10

I tried the following and it did not work

```
{{ render_form_row([form.variable1, form.variable2], row_class='no-gutters') }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended just using the following solution:

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">
        {{ render_field(form.variable1) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        {{ render_field(form.variable2) }}
    </div>
</div>
```